# How do i check what version of c++ compiler VS 2019 in using?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am learning c++ through a course and unfortunately the course uses a very basic IDE whereas I want to use Visual Studio 2019. In the course, it explicitly mentions to make sure that the compiler is using the right std version so that I will be able to compile the code snippets. It says that you need to pass an option --std=c++14 (or 17) to the g++ compiler. The problem is that in Visual Studio 2019 this compiler option is not easily apparent at all. Moreover, the code for verification of the __cplusplus directive keeps telling me I am using a compiler version from 1997.

Here is the code I am using for verification.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L)
        cout << "c++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L)
        cout << "c++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L)
        cout << "c++11\n";
    else
        cout << __cplusplus;
}
```

This outputs 199711.

I checked some c++ advanced options and manually set them to the following values:

[image]

But I still get 199711. I read that this is set by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160 but I can't find the compiler option to change this in VS2019.

I want to know how can I actually change this version in VS2019.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Brian I know that's the option, but I'm asking how to actually change it...

Comment: You are setting the language standard in the correct place in your screenshot. To get the `__cplusplus` directive to report the correct version you need to add the `/Zc:__cplusplus` option in the Command Line page.